# Syncing folders and files between a Windows and Linux system

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, sync

I want to sync some folders between my Windows 7 and Ubuntu computers. However, I don't want to sync everything inside each of the folder. I want to be able to choose which subfolders and files inside each folder to keep synced. Any new file added to this folder should automatically get synced.

Basically I want to create a link between multiple pairs of folders, but have the option to exclude some contents of the folders.

I would prefer this to be over the internet, but if it's over LAN that works too, as long as it is automatic.

Comment: Symlinks may works.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use some third-party tool such as Dropbox?

Comment: Dropbox doesn't do any of the things I mentioned. First, it only allows for one shared folder (not multiple). Second, inside that one folder everything gets uploaded to dropbox.

Comment: syncthing or rsync

Comment: Unison possibly if you don't care about it not being continuous.

Comment: @atype syncthing is perfect, thanks a lot. Put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you just create a mountable NTFS drive in windows (assuming your system is dual boot) and mount that drive on boot when in Linux?

Answer (score 7):

Doe you want continuous integration or do you want to control when the sync-ing is done?

1. In the first case, you can use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net).
2. In the second case, you can use [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

In both cases, you can control which folders/files are synchronised.

The set-up for syncthing is a bit more automated. You *can* turn on/off syncthing to control when synchronisation takes place but it is a bit tricky as you need to control both machines to do this.

In the case of unison, you need to set up "ssh" access between the two machines which may or may not be a problem depending on firewall configurations and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I do this at home and at my in-laws. The basic setup is to do a mount on the Linux system that points to the Windows system. Then, do a scheduled CRON job that runs an RSYNC job to copy the latest files. The initial job takes the longest.

One thing that is of interest is the credentials needed from the Linux system. I created a maintenance account on the Windows system. Also, if I recall, I had to share the folders I needed to access in one or more of the setups. Accessing the c$ hidden share stopped working at some point during Windows updates and upgrades, and a real share was needed.

And, after the Windows 7 to 10 upgrade, I remember that I had to search Google like hell for the syntax needed to access the remote system. Ended up finding some fancy NTLM command line switches that you will never guess on your own.

Have had to tweak several times over the past 5 years for Linux and Windows changes - so don't expect the first settings to last forever.

W.

Comment: Can you please show us an example rsync statement that you use?  I use it a lot and this answer sounds technically correct yet does not contain all the information required to duplicate what you are doing.  Also, please show the fancy NTLM stuff, etc.  Just mentioning them is great but not all that helpful.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been here in a while. Alas, he setup died over the summer due to 4 days of bad power during a heatwave. Even with a UPS, the system got fired. Hoping to get a replacement system and also hoping the Harddisks are reuseable.

Comment: Opps - got cut off. As for the fancy NTLM stuff - yes it was a pain. Plus, the Win8.1 to Win10 upgrade broke it. If I recall correctly, my last tweak was to create a new local Windows user with admin privs and use that account. Additionally, I think I had to create a share on the Windows system pointed to their my docs folder, and the permissions were given to only the user I mentioned above. There was one other catch I recall in that the password on the account could not use special chars. So I made it extra long, but with only numbs and letters.

Comment: *** Had to truncate at 350 chars

Perhaps my next kick at this will do it in reverse in that I will setup an SMB share on the linux server and then run a scheduled job on the windows system that uses a program I have used in the past. It's called Cobian backup. It's free and has worked for me beautifully. Gets installed as a service and has good compression, scheduling, logging, alerts, and differential options.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the good solutions provided here, you may also try using windows preinstalled onedrive. Its over the internet as you prefer plus gives you control over what folders/subfolders to sync. And on your linux you can install the onedrive app from software center. And download and sync your files with windows.